# elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client vs elasticsearch-rest-client

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient, elasticsearch-rest-client

I'm new to Elastic search. Started building a Spring boot application with Elastic search.

Using the latest ES version "elasticsearch-7.7.1" and for integration, I'm using below maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.7.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

I've faced issue in application startup, fixed by adding below dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Can anyone explain why `elasticsearch-rest-client` needed and how it differs from `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client`?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-overview.html) it mentions below:

> **Java Low Level REST Client:** the official low-level client for
>   Elasticsearch. It allows to communicate with an Elasticsearch cluster
>   through http. Leaves requests marshalling and responses un-marshalling
>   to users. It is compatible with all Elasticsearch versions.
>
> **Java High Level REST Client:** the official high-level client for
>   Elasticsearch. Based on the low-level client, it exposes API specific
>   methods and takes care of requests marshalling and responses
>   un-marshalling.

Best way to understand more on this is to read the javadocs for which below are the links respectively

- [High Level Rest Client Javadoc](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.7.1/index.html)
- [Low Level Rest Client Javadoc](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.7.1/org/elasticsearch/client/package-summary.html)

`High Level Rest Client` makes use of `Low Level Rest Client` which I believe, means, it ***extends classes and interfaces*** of `Low Level Rest Client`.

Advantages of using `High Level` over `Low Level` are:

- Avoid developers to re-write code or in other words maintainability and readability of code.
- Helps developers understand and co-relate with ES's API usage like that of using Kibana
- If any of xpack features are to be used as well(graph or ml), High Level Client API has the client code available which could be used without hassle of rewriting everything using low level API.

Below sample examples can help I guess:

### Example 1: Get a particular document

**With High Level Rest Client:**

```
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest("posts", "1");
```

**With Low Level Rest Client:**

```
Request request = new Request("GET", "/posts/1");
```

### Example 2: Search API

**With High Level Rest Client:**

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("posts");
```

You can refer to [this](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.7.1/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.html#search(org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest,org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions)) link

**With Low Level Rest Client:**

You would need to make use of `Request` and `Response` classes(low level) and using appropriate end-point

```
Request request = new Request("GET", "/posts/_search");
```

### Example 3: Analyze text:

**With High Level Rest Clent:**

Make use of [AnalyzeRequest](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.7.1/org/elasticsearch/client/indices/AnalyzeRequest.html) class

**With Low Level Rest Client:**

Use again `Request` and `Response` class

Basically working on `High Level Rest Client` is like working on *Elasticsearch's API layer (which indirectly works via HTTP packages)* while `Low Level` is purely working on HTTP i.e. [Request](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.7.1/org/elasticsearch/client/Request.html) and [Response](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.7.1/org/elasticsearch/client/Response.html) models i.e. a higher abstraction.

Hope that helps!

Comment: nice explanation, Thanks